# Naive Bayes without model

Tags: inference, naive-bayes

I have the following scenario:

I have two "states". I measure variables $n$ that are affected by the state. A state of 0 is the background state and in this case I expect each variable $n_i$ to be drawn from a normal distribution $N_i$~$(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ for which I already estimated the parameters. When the state is 1, I expect the variables to have a higher value than what you would expect from the background value, but I don't have any knowledge as to what exact distribution they will follow.

I would like to calculate, given an observation of the variables, how likely I am to be in state 1 relative to state 0.

It seems like Naive Bayes would be the correct solution, as I expect the variables to be mostly independent. I can calculate the probabilities relevant to state 0, e.g. probability of the observation given state 0. However, how do I calculate the probability of the data given state 1 if I do not know the distribution?

Another thought I had was that perhaps the approach should be different, for example calculate a z-score for each variable, and test that distribution. I guess it would be centered at zero for state 0 and higher at state 1. How would I test that? T-test?

Any thoughts are welcome.